# TFS automated test using custom test framework, SoapUI

Tags: testing, tfs, soapui

I have heard that we can integrate Unit Testing as a part of TFS build process. Which also control the build status (Success/fail). and also return the list of test that passed and failed.

But that is all based on nUnit or .Net testing framework. Is there anyway I hook my own testRunner, execute it and feed the result to TFS on every build? For information I want to use SoapUI testrunner as a my custom testrunner.

Answer (score 1):

Yes - you need to create a Test Adapter so that VS and the Build server can pick up the tests.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bhuvaneshwari/archive/2012/03/13/authoring-a-new-visual-studio-test-adapter.aspx

Above is a good article on how to do this.